# jQuery get the attr of elements into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lists of img and divs. I want to get the src of images and height, left of divs. This is my code:

```
<img class="img-bg" src="test.jpg">
<div class="rectangle" style="left: 252px; height: 198px;"></div>
<img class="img-bg" src="test1.jpg">
<div class="rectangle" style="left: 202px; height: 108px;"></div>


<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    var counter = 0;
    $('.img-bg').each(function() {     

      var src = $(this).attr("src"); 
      arr[counter] = new Array(src);
        counter++;
    });
    var counter = 0;

    $('.rectangle').each(function() {

      var width = $(this).css("left");
      var height = $(this).css("height");
      arr[counter].push(width, height);
      counter++;

    });


 console.log(arr[0]);
 console.log(arr[1]);


});
```

This is working but I wonder if any better solutions of my problem.

Edit:
Everything should be in 1 array. Something like this 
["test.jpg", "252px", "198px"]
["test1.jpg", "202px", "108px"]

Comment: Don't do `new Array()` just try `.push()`

Comment: can you share the desired result format

Comment: Should everything be in 1 Array or in multiple ones? As Arun mentioned what should the result be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/), and [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = $('.img-bg').map(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next('.rectangle');
        return [[$this.attr("src"), $next.css('left'), $next.css('height')]]
    }).get();

    console.log(arr[0]);
    console.log(arr[1]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5mybd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var srcArray = [];
var leftArray = [];
var heigthArray = [];
$("img").each(function () {
    srcArray.push($(this).attr("src"));
});


$("div").each(function () {
    leftArray.push($(this).css("left"));
    heigthArray.push($(this).css("height"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)**:

```
var srcArr = $('.img-bg').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("src");
}).get();
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7BdL/)

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<script>

var src1=[], left1=[], heigth1=[],counter1=0,counter2=0;

$("img").each(function(){

  src1[counter1]=$(this).attr("src");
  counter1+=1;
 });


$("div").each(function(){
  left1[counter2]=$(this).css("left");
  heigth1[counter2]=$(this).css("height");
    counter2+=1;
 });

</script>
```

Demo=> http://jsfiddle.net/5mybd/4/